# Gtkmm Box Not Being Removed

Tags: c++, gtk, gtkmm

I'm creating an application using gtkmm, where I create a number of Gtk::Boxes then display them as need be to the screen. These boxes display Gtk::Entry widgets to get information from the user, along with other widgets.

My problem is that when I try and "remove" these boxes, they don't seem to actually get removed, so they take up memory which results in my application crashing. I'm unsure of why it's doing this, but what I find interesting is this: every time my "remove_widget" function (which removes the Gtk::Box I want removed) executes, I have a std::cout statement which displays "Container Removed". Each time, it should theoretically only remove the container element (the Gtk::Box). But each subsequent time it runs, the number of "Container Removed" statements doubles. So the first time it gets displayed once, the next time it gets displayed twice, then four times, then eight, etcetera.

Anyways, the core of what I want to do is add a specific box to the window, get information from it, then destroy it should I can add a different Gtk::Box. I don't know if this method is the best way to do this, but as of right now it's how I'm going about it. Anyways, here is the code to get you an idea. What's happening is that I load MainWin, which creates a new window. Then MainWin packs an Event_Controller box into it, and the Event_Controller handles displaying the other boxes I want to display for the user. on_new_flight_clicked() handles the displaying the first box, and on_next_clicked handles the displaying the rest of the boxes.

```
class MainWin : public Gtk::Window {
public:
  MainWin();
  virtual ~MainWin();

protected:
  // signal handler
  void on_button_clicked(Glib::ustring data);

  // Flight Data Object
  Flight flight;
  // Member widgets:
  Gtk::Box main_container_box;  // Holds everything in the window
  Gtk::Button new_comp; // Allows the user to create a new competition
  Gtk::Button go_home;  // Allows the user to return to the main 
  screen
  Event_Controller* new_event;
};

class Event_Controller : public Gtk::Box {
public:
  Event_Controller(Flight& tflighto);
  virtual ~Event_Controller();

protected:
  Flight* flight;
  Gtk::Box* container_box;
  void on_new_flight_clicked();
  void on_next_clicked(Glib::ustring data);
  void remove_widget();

  Gtk::Button next; // This will appear at every step of the create a 
flight sequence, except the end, taking the user to the next step
};

void Event_Controller::on_new_flight_clicked()
{
  container_box = new Gtk::Box; // Create a new container box
  add(*container_box); // Add it to the box
  container_box->pack_start(*Gtk::manage(new Flight_Letter(flighto)), 
Gtk::PACK_EXPAND_WIDGET); // Pack the first form into the container 
box
  add(next); // Pack the next button outside the container box
  show_all_children();  // Show everything
}

void Event_Controller::remove_widget()
{
  // Remove everything from Event_Controller, this is where I think* things go wrong
  remove(*container_box);
  delete container_box;
  container_box = nullptr;
  cout << "Container Removed..." << endl;

  remove(next);

  container_box = new Gtk::Box; // Create the container box
  add(*container_box);
}

void Event_Controller::on_next_clicked(Glib::ustring data)
{
  int figures_loop = 0;
  // This will show the Flight_Number form. Here is the general model 
for what we do in this function. This function
  // gets passed an argument, and that allows us to remove the form we 
need to and bring up a new form.
  if(data == "first")
  {

    // First we remove the previous form and the container
    remove_widget();
    // Then we set next to send a message to this function when it's 
clicked, so that it knows what form to bring up next
    next.signal_clicked().connect(sigc::bind<Glib::ustring> 
(sigc::mem_fun(*this, &Event_Controller::on_next_clicked), "first"));
    // Create the new form
container_box->pack_start(*Gtk::manage(new 
Figure_Number(num_of_figures)), Gtk::PACK_EXPAND_WIDGET);

    // Pack the next button
    pack_start(next);
    // Show all the widgets
    show_all_children();
  }
// There is more to this function, I just left it out for brevity sake
}
```

Thanks for any help ahead of time, and if anything is unclear or you have any suggestion/concerns/comments, feel free to comment further.

Comment: You should do some follow up on your older questions (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50110999/gtkmm-entry-widget-get-text-function-not-working-properly) for example) if you want people to keep helping you. Helping someone who seems to abandon his posts without any comment or answer is not very inviting...

Comment: worse: it's not an MCVE, so readers who may otherwise want to compile & analyse to help can't. It's also far from clear how you measured the leak, its magnitude, etc. Anyway, you don't `Gtk::manage()` `container_box`, so it'll leak when the `Event_Controller` is destroyed. That seems very wrong. (Once you fix that, note you *do* still need to `delete` after `remove`, as `gtkmm` refloats the reference in `Container.remove()`. Then you may as well just `delete` & let that `remove`.) Personally I'd just `container->box.foreach()` & `delete` its children. Then it can be a member value, not pointer